# Use WordPress with folder permissions <= 750

Tags: linux, wordpress, permissions, file-permissions

My web hosting provider daily resets all folder permissions to 750, but since a few days, I'm having problems with uploading images inside wordpress. When change permissions of upload folders to 755, everything works fine, but it is reset the next day... The provider told me, that 750 should be fairly enough, and I think the same, but I don't know how to do this with wordpress...

Answer (score 0):

The /wp-content/uploads/ directory needs to be writeable by the user that the web server runs under as when you upload files, it is the web server that is writing the new files to the uploads directory.

You need to change the ownership of the uploads directory to the web server user.  The username and the method to change the ownership are somewhat dependant on the server set up, but your web host should be able to help you set the correct ownership on the directory.

The difference between 755 and 750 is that 755 gives everybody write permission for the directory, with 750 only the owner and group have write permissions.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: That's exactly my problem: My username (let say "asdf") is the owner of all folders and files, and my guess is, that wordpress should also be running as "asdf". I found out that I actually can upload files, but they're not displayed afterwards, even though they're on the server. Changing their permission doesn't help. My provider now said, that wordpress uses 640 for uploaded files and doesn't check group permissions (I don't understand it fully). They gave me now permission 755 for /wp-content/uploads/ permanently as an exception. :)

Comment: It's great that it works now.  For reference, on a shared host, you won't likely be able to get the webserver (and hence 'WordPress') to run under your user name.  The webserver intentionally runs as an unprivileged user for security reasons (lfor instance by default as the username www-data on a Ubuntu server).  You would have to chown (change ownership) of the directory to this user. Going this route would be more secure than giving everyone write access to the directory. With 755 permissions any other user on the server could in theory write to the directory.

Comment: @Roscius, well you can execute files via socket or pool, which can be made run as account owner and its group. So files would be executed only by that user.